# Django - Disable Page Level Caching by User

Tags: django, caching, django-cache, django-caching

I've set up page level caching for many of our pages.  However once in a while an admin user logs in to preview potential changes to the site.

Is there a way to disable page level caching just for these users?

I read through [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/) but I didn't see anything.

Update:
Here's my attempt based on v1k45's answer:

```
from django.middleware.cache import FetchFromCacheMiddleware


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ExceptImpersonateFetchFromCacheMiddleware(FetchFromCacheMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        # Break out of caching is we're using impersonate
        if request.user and hasattr(request.user, 'is_impersonate') and request.user.is_impersonate:
            logger.warning("Skipping cache_page for user %s because it is impersonation" % str(request.user))
            request._cache_update_cache = False
            return None
        # Normal flow:
        return super(ExceptImpersonateFetchFromCacheMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the CacheMiddleware provided by django such that the admin users always see fresh content instead of cached.

Have a look at the source code for [`FetchFromCacheMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/middleware/cache/#FetchFromCacheMiddleware), you can see this code snippet:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    [...]
    if request.method not in ('GET', 'HEAD'):
        request._cache_update_cache = False
        return None  # Don't bother checking the cache.
```

The if condition here tells django to skip cache and don't update the existing cached data if the request method is not `GET` or `HEAD`.

Similarly, you can add a check where you skip the cache if the user is an admin. Roughly it will look like this:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    [...snip..]
    if request.user.is_staff:
        request._cache_update_cache = False
        return None  # Don't bother checking the cache.
```

**UPDATE**: The [`cache_page`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/views/decorators/cache/) decorator uses django's [`CacheMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/middleware/cache/) which extends the functionality of FetchFromCacheMiddleware and UpdateCacheMiddleware.

Now you'll have to make your own version of `CacheMiddleware` and `cache_page` decorator. This `custom_cache_page` decorator will call your `CustomCacheMiddleware` which extends your `CustomFetchFromCacheMiddleware` and django's `UpdateCacheMiddleware`.

After you have completed the CustomCacheMiddleware, you'll have to replace django's CacheMiddleware with your own. This can be done by changing MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple in settings.py.

Comment: This looks very promising!  Thanks!  What's the best way to do this?  Am I modifying Django's own source code, or is there a smarter way?

Comment: You are not modifying django's source code, you are just replacing a middleware provided by django which is meant to be replaceable any time. All you have to do is put your extended class' python path in your settings.py `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Are you saying to name my new class "FetchFromCacheMiddleware" to override Django's version?  I don't see "FetchFromCacheMiddleware" mentioned in settings.py in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: (Also I put my code in the question, does that look about right)

Comment: Hmm, upon further reading, the FetchFromCacheMiddleware is only for entire site caching, not the cache_page decorator?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you asked about per-site cache. You'll have to create a custom `cache_page` decorator. See the updated answer.